# Need to convert iOS 5.0 App to iOS 4.3.3

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, xcode4.2

I am developing my app in iOS 5.0 but i also want to convert it to iOS 4.3.3.

My Problem is that i get no compiler warnings or error when i install my app in iPhone 3GS(iOS 4.3.3). But app crashes when there is a call to iOS 5.0 and later supported functions.
Currently i am managing it by checking condition like this:-

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>4.4)
 {
     //Call iOS 5.0 and later function.
     //For example.
     [myTabBar setTintColor:maroonColor];
 }
 else
 {
     //Otherwise not do anything.
 }
```

Is there a way to convert iOS 5.0 app to iOS 4.3.3 easily. Or any settings related to maximum deployment target. So i can set it to 4.3.3 and get all errors at once iOS 5.0 supported functions.

Comment: You don't want to "convert" your app to 4.3.3. What you want is to set your Deployment Target to 4.3 so your app supports iOS 4.3 and later. Then use proper runtime checks to check for the existence of newer classes, methods, and frameworks. It's rare that you need to use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`.

Comment: I have to maintain runtime checks in whole application. My application is too big. It is a time consuming task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to look at [DeployMate](http://www.deploymateapp.com), which should list all possible incompatibilities. And I would use `if ([myTabBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor)])` rather than your code.

Comment: DeployMate looks good (and I'm tempted to try it for future projects), but it's commercial software - Apple's built-in Base SDK setting does this already, for free.

Comment: also i think my code is really not good as your code. Your logic is excellent. You are too good MrMage.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's guide here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html

> "Choose a base SDK. Your software can use features available in OS
>   versions up to and including the one corresponding to the base SDK. By
>   default , Xcode sets this to the newest OS supported by Xcode."

...so: set your base SDK to iOS 4.3.3 (requires you to have 4.3.3 installed), and attempt to build.

EDIT: and if you don't still have a copy of SDK 4.3.3, you can get it via Apple's hidden (they don't link it from the iOS dev center :( ) downloads page: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=ios

Comment: This information is not really correct. In this case the OP wants the `Base SDK` set to "latest" and it is the `Deployment Target` that needs to be set to 4.3, not the `Base SDK`. You don't need a 4.3.3 SDK.

Comment: Why do you say that? The OP says: "So i can set it to 4.3.3 and get all errors at once"

Comment: Setting base SDK to latest will HIDE ALL ERRORS because they ARE NOT ERRORS with a base SDK of "latest" !

Comment: The OP wants to use newer APIs as well as support iOS 4.3. This requires the latest Base SDK and a proper Deployment Target of 4.3. Yes, this hides errors. But the solution is not to set the Base SDK to 4.3. Doing this will result in vastly more errors from all of the code using newer APIs.

Comment: Where are you getting that from? The OP states: "Is there a way to convert iOS 5.0 app to iOS 4.3.3 easily". In either case, the fastest way to achieve this is to switch to 4.3, triage all the errors, and then *if you wish to* switch the base SDK back to latest.

Comment: Look at the code in the question. It is obvious they want to use a method added in 5.0 if it is available.

Comment: That changes nothing that I said above. Have you ever added backwards-compatibility to a large, complex app? I have. The OP is asking (as I understand it) how to make Xcode help with the process. Apple specifically provided a system for doing this. I have used this on MANY projects. It works very well. I have no idea why you're so keen to discourage using the feature Apple provided!

Comment: I think I misread something, sorry. But still, there is no way to set the Base SDK to 4.3 (or 5.0, or 5.1, or 6.0) with the latest Xcode. You can only choose 6.1 (or "latest").

Comment: Please don't say "there is no way" - just read my answer. I do this every day.

Comment: PS: it's especially foolish to say you cannot set to 5.0, 5.1, or 6.0 - these are BUILT IN TO XCODE, all you have to do is hit cmd-, and there are 1-click install links for each one. If you don't know how to do something, fine. But don't post comments claiming it's "impossible".

Comment: I have Xcode 4.6 and there is no option to select anything other than iOS 6.1 or "latest" for the Base SDK. The Preferences pane does not offer you chance to download other SDKs. You can download other Simulators, but I see no place to download other SDKs. Xcode 4.6 only comes with one SDK - iOS 6.1 SDK. The others are not built into Xcode by default and Xcode doesn't offer the chance to download others. If you have others then you have done something that is not standard. The downloads link you posted lets you get older versions of Xcode. Explain how to install other SDKs into Xcode 4.6.

Comment: @rmaddy re: simulators - someone at Apple believes developers are too stupid to know what an "SDK" is. It says "Simulator", but it means "SDK" - after all, without an SDK, you *could not use* the Simulator you'd downloaded! If you try it, you'll find it's a complete SDK (which, of course, includes a Simulator)